# Indices dos tuplos numa lista - python

Tags: python, lista, tuple

Organização da informação no ficheiro

(Cidade,Cidade,Distancia)

```
import csv
with open('cidades.csv', 'r') as f:
       list1 = [tuple(line.values()) for line in csv.DictReader(f)]

for i in list1:
    x=(list1[i])
    print(distancia=x[2])
```

Para aceder ao índice 3, dos tuplos que copiei para a lista,e escrever para uma variável?

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi direito o que você quer, então por favor reformule sua pergunta. Mas se você quiser acessar o terceiro índice das tuplas na sua lista de tuplas, você pode fazer diretamente assim:

```
for i in range(len(list1)):
    x = list1[i][3]
    print(x)
```

Ou então, de forma mais simplificada:

```
for t in list1:
    x = t[3]
    print(x)
```

A forma como você fez está errada pois no seu for você está retornando uma tupla inteira, e não um índice para indexar em `list1`.